# How to assign the value in perl

Tags: perl

Getting the User profile Details in  response

```
$response = $client->fql->query( query => 'SELECT name, email, birthday, username, first_name, last_name, pic FROM user WHERE uid = me()');
```

After that print the statement like:

```
print join "\n Name:",  sort map { $_->{name} } @$response;
print "</br>\n";
print join "\n Email:",  sort map { $_->{email} } @$response;
print "</br>\n";

sort map { $_->{email} } @$response;
```

I want to assign this to one variable and  to compare and check the values.
How to assign the value to the variable and store?

Comment: `I want to assign this to one variable and to compare and check the values. How to assign the value to the variable and store?` Please define: `this`, `the value` and `store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"How to assign the value in perl?"***

More info. at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators .

***" ... to compare and check the values"***

More info. at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator .

***" ... and store?"***

```
 o_O
```

Comment: By this way i am reading the value now 
my %ED = map { $_->{email} } @$response;
print %ED; 
But still i want to compare the email  with another variable  so how to compare the hash variable value with another scalar variable value?

Comment: **"how to compare the hash variable value ..."** I would use the key of this supposed value to work with the "value" in order to take then profit of the powerful perl [regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). Anyway, or the question appears more defined/simplified or I think I will not be able to help you a lot. I hope somebody can. Sorry!

Comment: I have changed some other way to read and store the value and also to compare the values with other values here i have the code

my @EmailID = map { $_->{email} } @$response;
my $mailID;
$mailID = $EmailID[0];
we can use the $mailID ro any other process.